# Average value of polygons within a set distance from a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, distance, spatial-analyst, proximity

I have two vector layers: one polygon and one point layer. The polygon layer has a value from 1 to 10. I am trying to find the average value for all polygons within or partly within a 1-mile radius of each of the points in the points layer. What would be the best way to go about this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and I have access to the Spatial Analyst extension.

Comment: When you say "value" of the polygons, what are you referring to?

Comment: I should have specified this. I am referring to a column containing values from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Buffer Tool with your points and then use the Spatial Join tool.  For the Spatial Join make the point buffers the target and the polygons the join features with the One To One option and change the merge property of the column with the values you want averaged in the field list to use Mean instead of Sum (or add a new field to the field list if you want both the sum of the values and the mean in separate fields).  The point buffers and Spatial Join output will retain the FID of the original points in a field, so you can transfer the Mean from the Spatial Join output into the original points using a standard Join and the Field Calculator.

Technically you do not have to do the Buffer, since you can set a radius/tolerance for the Spatial Join tool to function like a buffer.  However, the Buffer tool is fast and the Spatial Join tool will run much faster when you use a radius/tolerance of 0.

Comment: ...And if you use the buffer, it gives you a nice visualization of the process!

Comment: Didn't see this, you beat me to it!

Comment: crmackey I do like the screen shot in your answer.  Anyway, the similarity of our two answers confirms that the method we have outlined is a typical approach to solving a problem like this.

Comment: Agreed.  Seems like the easiest way to do it.

Comment: With 1:1 join what is going to happen to polygon sitting within 100m from point A and 200m from point B?

Comment: Both points will include that polygon's value in the set of values used to determine the mean value for the field you choose.  There would be no distinction between the two points as long as the buffer is 200m or larger.  If you want some distinction in the set of polygons considered by the points within different distances you may have to create ring buffers and process them separately.  You would have to give more information about why you may want a distinction if you do want different distances grouped separately to get a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using a spatial join of the Polygons to your Points.  Set the Join option to `JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE` and in the Field Mappings, right click on your value field from the Polygons and set the merge rule to `Mean`.  For the Search Distance, set that to 1 mile.  That should give you the average of all polygons within 1 mile of the points (see screenshot below).

[image]